# What is the Oracle equivalent of SQL Server's SET NOCOUNT ON?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql

What is the Oracle equivalent of SQL Server's SET NOCOUNT ON?

From the [SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx):

> SET NOCOUNT ON... Stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set...
>
> For stored procedures that contain several statements that do not return much actual data, or for procedures that contain Transact-SQL loops, setting SET NOCOUNT to ON can provide a significant performance boost, because network traffic is greatly reduced.

Comment: "SET FEEDBACK OFF" at SQL*plus prompt. For a reference http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html

Comment: @BigMike that should be an answer with a link to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2698970

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Oracle when `set nocount on` is used inside a stored procedure, simply because it's not necessary to do (inside a procedure or function).

The only vaguely matching thing is `set feedback off` as mentioned by BigMike

Comment: I don't know SQL Server, but reading that docs, it seems that if I execute a script with several queries, it returns something like a resultset (or a similar data structure) containing each query results and an informational row containing the number of rows affected by previous instruction. If it really works this way, I can see why setting that option can improve perf. Am I right on this ?

Comment: @BigMike: I rarely have to use SQL Server myself, but that is my understanding as well. Additionally I *think* it also affects the result set returned by the stored procedure (but it's been ages since I had to code in T-SQL)

Answer (score 4):

`SET FEEDBACK OFF` at SQL*plus prompt.

For official docs please refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2698970)

Comment: That documentation suggests that the command only has effect when executing a statement at the SQL*plus prompt. In SQL Server `SET NOCOUNT` affects the behaviour even in non-interactive scenarios. From the MS docs "For stored procedures that contain several statements that do not return much actual data, this can provide a significant performance boost because network traffic is greatly reduced." Is this true of `SET FEEDBACK` too?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw I've never seen performance impacts setting setting FEED ON or OFF. Normally SET FEED & other options are related to report generation (yeah, you can get pretty reports with SQL*Plus). It's a bit different from MS Management Studio. I sincerely doubt that performing a SET NOCOUNT in a stored procedure and calling it via jdbc or ADO or something other will cut execution times.

Comment: SET FLUSH can sometimes improve SQL*Plus performance, but it manages flushing the output (formatted or not), of sql*plus application.

Comment: Here's the docs for `SET NOCOUNT`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx. It's possible (likely?) that Oracle has no equivalent of SQL Server's `DONE_IN_PROC` messages.

Comment: I think it's quite different. Number of messages written by SQL*Plus is arguably obtained by counting fetched rows, not obtained via a specific message, but it's just a blind shot of mine. Disabling video output can lead to performance improvements, but just because it cuts out visualization time.